# Excel email attachment using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, email, email-attachments

Need to attach excel file in outlook email. I need to use the user name and password as well.

Getting the error

```
excel_file=r'D:\\vvvv\\bbbb\\aaaa\\xxxx\\abc.xlsx'

def send_mail_with_excel(recipient_email, subject, content, excel_file):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = SENDER_EMAIL
    msg['To'] = recipient_email
    msg.set_content(content)

    with open(excel_file, 'rb') as f:
        file_data = f.read()
    msg.add_attachment(file_data, maintype="application", subtype="xlsx", filename=excel_file)

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587) as smtp:
        smtp.login(SENDER_EMAIL, APP_PASSWORD)
        smtp.send_message(msg)
   
send_mail_with_excel(recipient_email, subject, content, excel_file)
```

Error:

```
Input In [78] in send_mail_with_excel
    with open(excel_file, 'rb') as f:

TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback please?

Comment: @Corralien I have a xlsx file in this path and when I use open(file_path,'rb') i'm getting the below error.
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: Do you have import `open` from a module like `from xxxx import open`?

Comment: yess I removed that now the code is working fine. Thank you @Corralien I had a Import *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message shows that the `open` function accept an integer and not a string so it's not the signature of the builtin function.

You probably have an import that overrides the `open` function like `from xxx import open` or worst `from xxx import *`

[Why is "import *" bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/15239951)

**Note**: `filename=excel_file` as parameter of `add_attachment` method should preferably be a filename and not a path.